# Plugin with id 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven' not found

Tags: gradle, salesforce

I am creating a native app Salesforce project using Android Studio.

The git repo has been cloned from https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-Templates

but while building code using Android Studio I'm getting with following error.
**Error:(2, 0) Plugin with id 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven' not found.**

Android Studio Version: 2.2.3(latest)

My builde.gradle code is as below:

```js
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven'
apply plugin: 'com.jfrog.bintray'

dependencies {
  compile project(':libs:SmartStore')
}

android {
  compileSdkVersion 25
  buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'

  buildTypes {
      debug {
         testCoverageEnabled = true
      }
  }
```

Please help me on this.

Comment: Did you try commenting that line?

Comment: @Hackerman: yes, I tried by commenting that second plugin statement but then it will give error to the third line i.e. apply **plugin: 'com.jfrog.bintray'** and if I tried to comment 3rd line also then so many different errors will generate.

Comment: I just checked the github repo and that project has been moved; I don't know if that is related to your problem...the new repo is this one https://github.com/simpligility/android-maven-plugin

Comment: Can you share your gradle version?